# Are there any fonts included with Windows 10 that only contain capital letters?

Tags: fonts

Are there any fonts that are included by default with Windows 10 that contain only capital letters?

I have an ordering system that's essentially just a database containing dates descriptions and prices. It's policy that all descriptions must be entered in all caps, all of the time. No exceptions.

This is non negotiable, I've already tried and failed to change this.

The problem is that most of the descriptions are sent to us in lower or mixed case by suppliers on emails or documents.

Meaning that they either need to be re-typed in again in upper case - which can be time consuming or which can lead to mistakes - or they need to be copied and pasted into another program like word and converted to upper case, and then cut and pasted into the system. Which is also time consuming and can also lead to mistakes (For example, copying the same line twice).

I can change the font used in the settings as this is set centrally and effects all users.

I can't use script to automatically change the case as it's simply not supported. It's not an option.

I can't install any new fonts as 1) The IT department says no and 2) The software is being used by lots of people and if someone opens a copy on a computer without the font installed it breaks the system, and the IT department won't install a new font on every computer.

The only option is to see if there is a default font installed already n Windows 10 that's all caps.

Does such a font exist and if so what's it name.

If not, a simply no as an answer would do.

Comment: An all-caps font would only change the *appearance* not the underlying text, which to a computer would still be in mixed case. Is this a print requirement or a 'computer-reading' requirement? [I haven't looked at Windows in quite some time. Doesn't it have a simple 'convert to upper/lower case' transform for text? Like this, on Mac - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EKUs.png - this is available in any text entry, system-wide.

Comment: @Tetsujin, the requirement for all caps is departmental policy. A person decided this, there is no greater logic to it and no technical reasons.

Comment: Then they need to specify their policy more carefully. That is not a definition technical enough to ensure compliance.

Comment: @Tetsujin, So long as the person accessing the software sees "all caps, all of the time", it doesn't really matter if the text is in upper or lower case. It's the appearance that's important.

Comment: Ah, OK… then just to make it harder for a human to read, they're not interested in what the computer thinks of it. Fine. You need an all-caps font. Back to your original question [idk on Win, sorry].

Comment: @Tetsujin, It's a style policy, not a technical policy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144862/discussion-between-aaargh-zombies-and-tetsujin).

Comment: On macOS there is a "Copperplate" font that shows lower case in smaller capital style letters so you can still tell the difference, idk about Windows. Just upper case feels like going back to computers from 50 years ago when I started.

Comment: Not sure where this fits in but the spreadsheet UPPER function will convert all text to upper case

Comment: @Blind Spots, not all software supports scripting.

Comment: can you install software?

Comment: @Keltari, I can't even install new fonts. Running software or using scripts is out.

Comment: I mentioned UPPER because of the mention of copying and pasting to spreadsheet

Comment: The answer is "no". MS did *not* include ALL CAPS fonts, and you can't make that happen retroactively.

Comment: You need to talk to your IT and/or management.   This would be a very simple issue to fix with third party software.  Explain you would work faster and make fewer mistakes with a proper solution.

Comment: @Keltari, first thing I tried. They said press the caps lock key.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik, then why not put this in the form of an answer, why did you mention time travel, this isn't a a question about game design so plot suggestions are unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the default [Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) and [Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_11_font_list) font list, there doesn't seem to be.

You can also check the Windows [Font Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such built-in option.

I'd suggest to either enforce users to capitalize all text when required or create a solution to capitalize it when processing.

---

You mentioned Excel, in this case you can use =UPPER("text") function. You can encase it in VBA macro and start it after copying data (or even create button inside of spreadsheet to start it). Example script for capitalizing whole "B" column:

```
Sub tgr()

With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)")
End With

End Sub
```

You could also create AutoHotkey script to capitalize selected text (or in reality: copy it and retype as capitalized). This should work with any software but it does have limitation: as it's typing, it can break text with special characters. Example script working with ctrl+win+u:

```
^#u::
Clipboard := ""
Sleep 50
Send ^c
ClipWait
Send % "{Raw}" Format("{:U}", Clipboard)
return
```

Code sources:

VBA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991174/excel-macro-to-change-entire-column-to-uppercase

AutoHotkey: https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/nnpwer/how_to_convert_selected_text_from_lowercase_to/

Comment: this could be done with powershell as well: copy text, click a shortcut ont he taskbar to use powershell to transform the text on the clipboard, to upper case, then the user can paste to the cell or form or whatever.

Comment: @Yorik, I'm not arguing that it couldn't be done this way, but it doesn't answer the question, because it's a question about fonts rather than coding.